# Node.js created server makes 3 request on first page load and 2 request after each page refresh?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a server by help of node.js like :

```
var http = require('http'); //http comes build into the node

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
console.log('got a request!');
response.write('Hello sanjit!');
response.end();
});
server.listen(3000);
```

I run my server from command promote like:

```
c:\nodejs\node module1
```

nodejs is my main folder where everything lies. `module1` is that file which has my code. Now to know it works fine in every page load there should have 1 request at a time but I don't know why in my case when I first load `localhost:3000` it gives me 2 requests as it logs `got a request`.

I know something isn't right there. I mean if I was gone right way then I would have seen 1 request in first load of `localhost:3000` and after then also 1 request on every single page load. That's not happening with me and I'm confused.

I am using Chrome.

Again I wanna say that after I run my server I get 2 requests on first load of `localhost:3000` and after that 2 requests on every single page load on Chrome.

In Firefox things get little different. In first load `localhost:3000` I get 2 requests and after that in every single page load it works fine and I get only 1 request at every single page load.

What might be the problem?
How can I make it request 1 request at one page load?

Comment: Please don't use syntax `highlighting` for text that isn't code.

Comment: ok sorry bro how can I point out important words then?

Comment: _Cursive_ or __bold__ (`_Cursive_ or __bold__`). But use it ___sparingly___. No-one likes reading a text where a quarter of the words are bolded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. The browser actually does multiple requests by default.

The second request is usually a favicon.ico request. You can log which URL was called using `console.log(request.url);`

To make it work as you want it, you will want to work with a router. [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/router) could be one of your options. Then you have all the controls of all the URLs that the browser requests.

Comment: ok bro I am getting favicon.ico Can you explain more with some working code for not getting favicon.ico

Comment: I already have. You will need to use a router to filter through all the requests and only catch the ones you need. The link I provided shows you a very basic way to catch a "/" url which you most likely need.

Comment: thank bro it worked for me.I checked your link and added two package `router` and `finalhandler` which did what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

When you visit a page with chrome.

It will try to get /favecon.ico.

and you will have two request

```
/
/favecon.ico
```